# Angular: force resolve again

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My dependencies to be resolved rely on data which changes.  How do you force angular to resolve dependencies **again**?

```
  $routeProvider.
  when('/blah', {
    templateUrl: '/static/views/myView.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: {
        theData: function(myFactory) {
            return myFactory.promise;
        }
    }
  }).
```

i.e, every time this `when` block is executed I want to re-resolve the dependency.

Is this trivial, or not so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolve block is rechecked every time route changes. In your case you need to return new promise each time, instead of how you are doing it currently. Looks like you cache and return always the same promise object.

```
resolve: {
    theData: function(myFactory) {
        return myFactory.getSomething();
    }
}
```

Make `myFactory.getSomething` return new promise in each invocation.